# Which happens first for a Magus, spell effect or weapon damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magus

When using the Magus Spellstrike ability, which happens first, the spell or the weapon damage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not specified, which means it's up to your gamemaster to decide. In most cases it won't matter: the victim will take both the weapon damage and the spell effect. So the only way it could matter is if the spell effect somehow depends on the target's hit points. That's pretty unusual: I suppose you must be thinking of casting Vampiric Touch (that is the ONLY Magus spell I could think of where it would matter). For what it's worth, I would allow the drain to happen first, then the weapon damage, but it's not in the rules so it's your GM's call.

Comment: The other situation would be if the GM allows you to not spend the charge if the weapon damage incapacitates a creature... but I don't know if that was the intent.